# How to print from two lists

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have two lists with diffrent itemsas follows:

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7',]

days = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun',]
```

I want to print from both to look like this:

```
result = 1
         mon
         2
         tue
         3
         wed
         4
         thu.....etc
```

Is there such as code that does this?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip to combine two lists.

Answer (score 1):

The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function is probably what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

You can print such output with this.

```
for n, m in zip(numbers, days):
   print(n, m)
```

**Output -**

`1 mon
2 tue
3 wed
4 thu
5 fri
6 sat
7 sun`

Hope it helps.

**Update** - [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function combines two ***equal-length*** collections (e.g. list) together and produces a tuple object.

Answer (score 0):

This can resolve your problem.

```
<?php
//array 1
$numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7',];

// array 2
$days = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun',];

// use for loop
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    echo $numbers[$i].' '.$days[$i].'<br>';
} 
?>
```

**Output -** 
1 mon 
2 tue 
3 wed 
4 thu 
5 fri 
6 sat 
7 sun